# How to tell if TabBarItem is already Selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

So I have a `viewController` with a `tableView` that is being presented from a `tabBarController`. If the user taps the `tabBarItem` for the view that is **already** being shown, I want the `tableView` to scroll to the top. I have set the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` to be the `viewController` and then added the following method:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0 {
        //scroll to the top!
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `tableView` scrolls to the top **regardless** of the current view. So I tried to add a second condition that makes sure that the currently displayed view is the correct one but nothing seemed to be correct.

**TL;DR**

How can I tell that the user is tapping on the `tabBarItem` that is already selected?

Comment: Have you written `override` in front of `func tabBarController(...)`?

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo nope, I don't think it needs to have that. I can confirm that the function is being called, I'm having the problem of what should go inside the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `self.view.window != nil` to determine if the view of the vc is already displayed. Use `shouldSelect` delegate method, which is called before the selection.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {



    if viewController === self && self.isViewLoaded {

    // Please use viewController === self.navigationController
    // if self is a child of a UINavigationController. We should
    // compare the viewController with a direct child of the 
    // UITabController

        if self.view.window != nil {
            print("scroll to top")
        } else {
            print("Don't scroll to top")
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using shouldSelect rather than didSelect, but there is still logic errors here. When adding these two lines of codes: `print(self.isViewLoaded)
        print(viewController === self)`
I reveal that it always prints `true` and `false`

Comment: For some reason `viewController === self` (or something like `viewController == self`) always returns `false`

Comment: I guess your vc has a navigation controller. In this case you should use (viewController === self.navigationController). We want to compare the direct child of the tab bar controller. And you should use ===, because you want to make sure there two pointers refer to the same view controller.

Comment: @MattBart sorry I forgot to @ you

Comment: Awesome that is the bug  that I have been looking for! One thing about your answer though is that I had to add `tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0` because the views are being controlled by the tabBarController they are still loaded even if you are looking at a different tab, thus `self.isViewLoaded` is always true. So my statement looks like this: `if viewController === self.navigationController  && tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0 {` The if statement that you have is `true` even if a user selects the tab from another tab.

Comment: Will accept the answer when you correct the answer ;)